# Different static files for the same path but different domains on App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, url-routing

I'm running WordPress Network with custom domains on Google App Engine **Standard Environment** (so I can't use nginx or something).

What I want to do is to serve different static content for different domains but using the same path:

```
somedomain1.com/favicon.ico ----> static/somedomain1.com/favicon.ico
somedomain2.com/favicon.ico ----> static/somedomain2.com/favicon.ico
somedomain3.com/favicon.ico ----> static/somedomain3.com/favicon.ico
```

etc…

I tried to use domain names in `app.yaml` URL handlers, but it ain't work for me:

```
handlers:
- url: (http|https)://somedomain1.com/favicon.ico
  static_files: static/somedomain1.com/favicon.ico
  upload: static/somedomain1.com/favicon.ico
```

Is this possible by means of the standard environment of App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `app.yaml` URL routing for such purpose because the `handler` `url` configuration doesn't apply to the host/domain name portion of the URL, it only applies to **the file path** portion. From the `url` row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table (emphasis mine):

> **url**
>
> Required element under handlers. The URL pattern, as a regular
>   expression. The expression can contain groupings that can be referred
>   to in **the file path** to the script with regular expression
>   back-references. For example, `/profile/(.*)/(.*)` would match the URL
>   `/profile/edit/manager` and use edit and manager as the first and second
>   groupings.

In other words this portion of your configuration is not really valid:

```
url: (http|https)://somedomain1.com/favicon.ico`
```

You could complement your WordPress static offering with a small app which could take care of **dynamically** selecting a particular  artifact based on the domain in the request's URL.